# Realloc address causing an Abort (core dumped)

Tags: c, realloc, memory-address

I attempted implementation of a new feature on working code. However, I know from commenting out that the following lines of code are causing my program to crash.

```
tmp = (char*)realloc(list->array[list->size], sizeof(char)*nameLength);
list->array[list->size] = tmp;
```

`list->array[list->size]` is defined in a struct in a .h file. `list->size` is an int that increases as the size of the array increases. I know that the .h file is correct and am pretty certain the rest of my code was written correctly because I tested it all. However I can't seem to figure out this `realloc` function. Can somebody please help me? I've searched stackoverflow and couldn't find the answer. This is my first time posting a question on stackoverflow. I hereby promise to help others on this site if I can get some help with this problem.

```
typedef struct ArrayList
{
// We will store an array of strings (i.e., an array of char arrays)
char **array;

// Size of list (i.e., number of elements that have been added to the array)
int size;

// Length of the array (i.e., the array's current maximum capacity)
int capacity;

} ArrayList;
```

I didn't want to clutter the post with long code. But just in case someone can find something I overlooked I am posting my main.c.

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char buffer[32];
    ArrayList *L1 = createArrayList(-1);

    FILE *ifp = fopen("names.txt", "rb");
    //Read all names from the file and add them to L1.
    while (fscanf(ifp, "%s", buffer) != EOF)
        put(L1, buffer);

    //printf("the size is %d", L1->size);   //test

    for(i=0; i<L1->capacity; i++) { //free columns
        free((void*)L1->array[i]);
    }
    free((void*)L1->array); //free rows
    free((void*)L1); // free struct
    system("pause");
    return 0;
 }

 char * put(ArrayList *list, char *str)
 {
    int i = 0,length = 0, nameLength;
    char* tmp, tmp2;

  //free((void*)list->array[list->size]);   //free columns
  //list->array[list->size] = NULL;         //set old pointer to NULL
    nameLength = strlen(str)+1;             //Aquire length of name +1
    tmp = (char*)realloc(list->array[list->size], sizeof(char)*nameLength);
    list->array[list->size] = tmp;
  //list->array[list->size] = str;
  //strcpy(list->array[list->size], str);
    printf("the name in the .txt file is %s: put \n", list->array[list->size]);

  //if array is full add space
    length = (list->capacity)*2 + 1;
  //if ( list->capacity <= list->size ) {
        ArrayList *nlist = expandArrayList(list, length);
  //}
    list->size ++;
 }

 ArrayList *expandArrayList(ArrayList *list, int length)
 {
    int i;
    //create newCharArray
    char **newCharArray = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*)*(length+1));  //alocate rows//2
    for(i=0; i<length+1; i++) {  // should fill ten rows + 1//2
        newCharArray[i] = malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));          //alocate Columns
        newCharArray[i] = "yoO";
    }
    //copy old list-Array into newCharArray
    for( i=0; i<list->capacity; i++) { //was length
        newCharArray[i] = list->array[i];
    }
    //print the values you inserted     //test
    for( i=0; i<list->capacity + 1; i++) {//2
        printf("the value in slot %d is %s : expandArrayList \n", i, newCharArray[i]);
    }
    //free the list->array columns and rows
    for( i=0; i<list->capacity; i++) {
        free((void*)list->array[i]);
    }
    free((void*)list->array);
    //set adress of newCh.. = our old Struct
    list->array = newCharArray;
    //print to test we did what was asked //test
    for( i=0; i<length + 1; i++) {//2
        printf("value in slot %d is %s : expandArrayList \n", i, list->array[i]);
    }

    return list;
 }

 ArrayList *createArrayList(int length)
 {
    int ncolumns, nrows, i;
    char stringVar[5]; //set rows = empty
    if(length < DEFAULT_INIT_LEN)
        length = DEFAULT_INIT_LEN;
    nrows = length;

    ArrayList *theArray;
    theArray = (ArrayList*)malloc (sizeof(struct ArrayList));  //alocate struct
    theArray->array = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*(nrows)); //alocate Rows 10th row will be null

    for(i=0; i<nrows; i++) {  // should fill ten rows
        theArray->array[i] = (char*)malloc(2 * sizeof(char)); //alocate Columns //realloc later
        theArray->array[i] = '\0';  //(char*)"pointer char will be returned malloc(100*sizeof(char): char*100 will be alocated
    }

  //theArray->array[nrows] = '\0'; //should fill the 11'th pointer slot array index 10
    theArray->capacity = nrows; //total rows that are available for use ("not including last null")
    theArray->size = 0; //Amount of rows used
    printf("capacity = %d :createArraylist \n", theArray->capacity);

    return theArray;
}
```

Comment: in `put()`, you have commented out `strcpy(list->array[list->size], str);`.  Why?

Comment: In C, don't cast the return value of `malloc` or `realloc`, this can hide bugs, easily. If you didn't `#include` the right header, this could just be your error.

Comment: What is the value of the macro DEFAULT_INIT_LEN?

Comment: Wait, what? `newCharArray[i] = "yoO";`? Seriously? You know, that throws awway every one of those `malloc(100 *sizeof(char *))` calls, replacing each with a pointer to a string literal...

Comment: Also, in C, you should never cast the return value of `malloc()` or `realloc()`, nor should you cast the pointer that you're passing to `realloc()` or `free()`, and multiplying by `sizeof(char)` is pointless. `sizeof(char)` is *guaranteed* to be `1`.

Comment: Multiplying by `sizeof(char)` is indeed mathematical pointless because it is 1, but it has usefulness in documenting that the code was allocating a char array.  In any case, I rather promote instead `nameLength*sizeof(*tmp)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `expandArrayList()` function, you're wandering down your array, allocating storage for strings. After each allocation, however, you're immediately throwing away your pointer to allocated storage, and replacing it with a pointer to `"yoO"`, a string literal. String literals are arrays of char, but they are not allocated with malloc(), do not belong to you, and you aren't allowed to `free()` or `realloc()` them. Slightly further down the same function, however, when you're trying to free the previous copy of the array list, guess what you're passing to `free()`?

### Edit

In `createArrayList()`, you do nearly the same thing, except that each allocated pointer that you throw away, you're replacing with `'\0'`, which is, effectively, a null pointer in this context.

Not to mention, how in `expandArrayList()`, immediately after filling each slot with a newly `malloc()`ed piece of memory (and then throwing it away...), you immediately copy the pointers from the old array list (which you subsequently also `free()`...)

Comment: I deleted the casts ,"yoO" and '0' and made the other minor changes suggested. the code ran smoothly. The only thing i still don't understand is how to correctly free space for the char** in the struct ArrayList. i want to make sure my destroy function doesn't segfault when passed a null pointer. here's my function. did i do it correctly?

Comment: ArrayList *destroyArrayList(ArrayList *list){

    int i;

    if( list == '\0' )
    return '0';

    for(i=0; i<list->capacity; i++){ //free columns
        free((void*)list->array[i]);
    }
    free((void*)list->array); //free rows

    free((void*)list); // free struct
    list = '\0';

return list;
}

Comment: BTW i learned much from your comments. I extend my gratitude. You guys have encouraged me to help others on stackoverflow. this website is an awesome idea i hope this post helps others.

Comment: You're still casting the pointers that you're passing to `free()`. You shouldn't. Also, `'\0'` is a character constant, not a null pointer. In pointer context, you should be using `NULL` for assignment and comparison, not `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
char **newCharArray = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*)*(length+1));
```

There is a problem in your allocation, you cast to char* instead of char**, and your variable is named CharArray whereas it's an array of C strings. Anyway in C you don't need to cast the return of malloc, just remove the cast completely.

```
for(i=0; i<length+1; i++) {  // should fill ten rows + 1//2
    newCharArray[i] = malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));          //alocate Columns
    newCharArray[i] = "yoO";
}
```

In `expandArrayList` you forgot a level a dereferenciation, you probably wanted:

```
for(i = 0; i<length+1; i++) {
    newCharArray[i] = malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(newCharArray[i], "yo0");
}
```

And in createArrayList you did the same error:

```
for(i=0; i<nrows; i++) {  // should fill ten rows
    theArray->array[i] = (char*)malloc(2 * sizeof(char)); //alocate Columns //realloc later
    theArray->array[i] = '\0';  //(char*)"pointer char will be returned malloc(100*sizeof(char): char*100 will be alocated
}
```

You wanted to do something like this:

```
for(i=0; i<nrows; i++) {
    theArray->array[i] = malloc(2);
    *(theArray->array[i]) = '\0';
}
```